# Is ChangeCipherSpec a part of handshake message in tls 1.2?

Tags: tls

Is changecipherspec a part of handshake message in transport layer security (tls) 1.2 because according to rfc5246"ChangeCipherSpec messages, alerts, and any other record types are not handshake messages and are not included in the hash computations. Also, HelloRequest messages are omitted from handshake hashes."

Comment: Yes: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.1

Comment: but according to rfc5246 it is given in  7.4.9 that "ChangeCipherSpec messages, alerts, and any other record types are not handshake messages and are not included in the hash computations.Also, HelloRequest messages are omitted from handshake hashes."

Comment: It's not part of the `handshake_messages` struct, but it's still a part of the handshake protocol. What you're asking is whether it's part of the hash. It is not. That does not mean it's not part of the handshake.

Comment: Please include that information in your question. However, 7.1 is under chapter 7.  The TLS Handshaking Protocols. I mean, therefore it is a handshake message as it is *defined* as such. Period.